# Why does the size of an R dataframe seem to depend upon its dimensions?

Tags: r, dataframe

Why does the size of an R dataframe seem to depend upon its dimensions ?

```
> z <- matrix(runif(10000))
> data.frame(matrix(z, nrow=200) ) %>% object.size()
86608 bytes
> data.frame(matrix(z, nrow=20) ) %>% object.size()
140608 bytes
```

Comment: Up front, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html. A vector has overhead, so when you have more vectors, you have more overhead. There's more to it, I suggest you go through the components of the frame. For instance, note that the difference between `object.size(runif(1))` and `object.size(runif(10))` and `object.size(runif(100))` are not just a matter of the length of numbers, there is the overhead associated with each, including 4 bytes of header and next/previous pointers for each value.

Comment: In R, data.frames are essentially lists of column vectors. Each column vector has it's own overhead to store the data, so the more columns you have, the more memory is used to do the accounting for those columns. Plus, if you have more columns, you have more column names and those take up memory as well. Normally the extra memory cost is worth it because keeping data in a column in contiguous memory makes it much easier to perform column wise transformations.